# regular expressions for the guid

Tags: regex, go

I'm having some issues with following regular expressions.

> Error: Invalid operation

```
re := regexp.MustCompile("(([a-f0-9]+\-)+[a-f0-9]+)\/(.*?)\/(.*?);version=(\d*)")
match := re.FindStringSubmatch(hex.EncodeToString([]byte(href)))
fmt.Println(match)
```

my test strings that I'm trying to match are

```
/data/1221a7f47-84c1-445e-a615-ff82d92e2eaa/article/jane;version=1493756861347

/data/1221a7f47-84c1-445e-a615-ff82d92e2eaa/article/john;version=1493756856398
```

Expecting following strings after match

1. 1221a7f47-84c1-445e-a615-ff82d92e2eaa
2. article
3. jane
4. 1493756856398

Comment: FYI: You need to declare the regex as a raw string literal, or double the backslashes.

Comment: sorry, can you help me with the code, I'm new to go lang, i want to go for string literal approach instead of double backslashes, appreciate your help

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/Dzg3JC/1/codegen?language=golang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix the first line, declare the regex correctly. Try these:

**Using backslashes** (to escape)

```
re := regexp.MustCompile("(([a-f0-9]+\\-)+[a-f0-9]+)\\/(.*?)\\/(.*?);version=(\\d*)")
```

[Try it out](http://ideone.com/Jonc1Y)

**Using raw string literals** (`)

```
re := regexp.MustCompile(`(([a-f0-9]+\-)+[a-f0-9]+)\/(.*?)\/(.*?);version=(\d*)`)
```

[Try it out](http://ideone.com/qyZUIe)

Comment: you mentioned string literal approach, can you amend with option B as well please?

Comment: Sure thing. Updated! Try it out now

Comment: oh i see, got it. by the way I'm not getting any matches, can you try against my test strings

Comment: @user2727195 your regex seems to be fine. Check out the [try it out](http://ideone.com/Jonc1Y) link in the answer which has output from the regex match operation. All you have to do now is ensure that `re.FindStringSubmatch()` is getting the right input.